# Image size shifts when page loads

Tags: wordpress, image, resize, load

I have a ghost-in-the-machine it seems: I have put a thumbnail with a rollover stage on a Wordpress site I'm working on. It works fine except that it does this strange resizing when the page loads. A small but very annoying thing.

[This is the page](http://www.cineliciouspics.com/dylz/)

I've also added the same code to [another Wordpress site](http://www.theyogaroomgisborne.co.nz/xx/) I am working on, which is based on the same theme (Quark). It doesn't happen on the other site.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Can you provide the code you're using for the rollover, including the urls you're using to get the image? Also, when you say 'strange resizing' that is a bit vague: can you describe what happens and what you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using percentages to define the widths of the containers and images, which is fine. However, upon initial page load, not all of your elements are available yet, so the relative percentages gradually reach their end-point when the document finishes loading. Doesn't look like like it's doing too much on my screen but in order to get around this you can load the images via jquery and set it to `$(document).ready` which will wait until the page is done loading, to even load the iamges.

Comment: ah ha! thanks, such a simple fix. i actually just added this plugin that makes the page fade in... and the page needs to be fully loaded before it will start, so that seems to do the trick. thanks for your help!

Comment: Awesome! Good thinking on your end with the plugin!